# Using pd.concat to union multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to union multiple dataframes I create from a given function. I have tried using pd.concat but get the error message:

> TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you
>   passed an object of type "DataFrame"

This is the code I have written:

```
def plot_percs(sims,name):
    filter = name
    session_to_leads = (sims['session_to_leads'].sum()/len(sims['session_to_leads']))*100
    leads_to_opps = (sims['lead_to_opps'].sum()/len(sims['lead_to_opps']))*100
    oops_to_comp = (sims['oops_to_comp'].sum()/len(sims['oops_to_comp']))*100
    percentages = pd.DataFrame(data=[filter,session_to_leads,leads_to_opps,oops_to_comp]).transpose()
    percentages.columns = ['filter','session_to_leads','leads_to_opps','opps_to_complete']
    return percentages
pd.concat(plot_percs(originalsims,'original'),plot_percs(facebooksims,'facebook'))
```

Here is a sample of both dataframes
originalsims:

```
    filter  session_to_leads    leads_to_opps   opps_to_complete
 0 original       16.28               9.47           1.92
```

facebooksims

```
    filter  session_to_leads    leads_to_opps   opps_to_complete
0  facebook       1.76                0.02             0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `[]` for list of `DataFrame`s passed to `pd.concat` function, also is possible add `ignore_index=True` for avoid duplicated index in output:

```
df = pd.concat([plot_percs(originalsims,'original'),
                plot_percs(facebooksims,'facebook')], ignore_index=True)
```

I think your function should be rewritten with `mean`:

```
def plot_percs(sims,name):
    c = ['session_to_leads', 'lead_to_opps', 'oops_to_comp']
    d = {'oops_to_comp':'opps_to_complete'}
    percentages = sims[c].mean().to_frame().T.rename(columns=d)
    percentages.insert(0, 'filter', name)
    return percentages
```